# PyQt5 - Can QTabWidget content extend up to Main Window edges, even with no content?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I am new to PyQt5... Simple question here.

I am using PyQt5 to build a simple application. This application has a Main Window containing a QTabWidget with 3 tabs. Once the application starts, all tab pages are empty and get filled later on. When tab pages are empty, I would still like them to appear as blank pages and extend up to the Main Window edges.

I've been trying to achieve this in two ways: using a layout and using the setGeometry function. Yet the tab pages never extend vertically very far, and horizontally they never go beyond the last tab. See code below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

       super().__init__()

       self.setWindowTitle("Window With Tabs")
       self.setGeometry(50,50,400,400)

       oTabWidget = QTabWidget(self)

       oPage1 = QWidget()
       oLabel1 = QLabel("Hello",self) 
       oVBox1 = QVBoxLayout() 
       oVBox1.addWidget(oLabel1)      
       oPage1.setLayout(oVBox1)

       oPage2 = QWidget()
       oPage2.setGeometry(0,0,400,400)

       oPage3 = QWidget()
       oPage3.setGeometry(0,0,400,400)              

       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage1,"Page1")
       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage2,"Page2")
       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage3,"Page3")      

       self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    oMainwindow = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Any idea how to modify the code so the empty pages will extend up to the edges of Main Window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a layout on the main widget:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):   
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Window With Tabs")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,400,400)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        oTabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(oTabWidget)
```

The `setGeometry` calls on the other widgets are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # window object
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.initGUI() # call custom code

    def initGUI(self):   
       self.setWindowTitle("Window With Tabs") # window...
       self.setGeometry(50,50,400,400)         #...properties   
       TabW=self.createTabs()                  # a custom-tab object
       layout = QVBoxLayout(self)              # main window layout   
       layout.addWidget(TabW)                  #populate layout with Tab object
       self.show()                             # display window   

    def createTabs(self):            # create and return Tab object
       oPage1 = QWidget()            # tabs...
       oPage2 = QWidget()
       oPage3 = QWidget()

       oTabWidget = QTabWidget()    # Tabobject

       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage1,"Page1") # populate tab object...
       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage2,"Page2")
       oTabWidget.addTab(oPage3,"Page3") 

       return   oTabWidget              # return tab object  

if __name__ == "__main__":             # Rest is History!

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    oMainwindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```